# FLashLoan aave v3

Tags: python, solidity

I'm trying to make a flash loan using Aave V3. On the interface, there's a function called `flashLoanSimple()`, shown here:

```
function flashLoanSimple(
    address receiverAddress,
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes calldata params,
    uint16 referralCode
) external;
```

The console returns an error:

> ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'The execution failed due to an exception.'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.

I don't know which is the trouble, because I deposit Dai on the contract address, then try to make the flashLoan and failure.

Here's the full code:

```
contract Flasher is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase, Withdrawable {
constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider _providerAddress)
    FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(_providerAddress)
{}

function flashLoanSimple(address asset, uint256 amount) external {
    require(asset != address(0), "Address zero no");
    require(amount > 0, "Pone plata");
    address receiverAddress = address(this);
    uint256 _amount = amount * 10**18;
    bytes memory params = "";
    uint16 referralCode = 0;

    POOL.flashLoanSimple(
        receiverAddress,
        asset,
        _amount,
        params,
        referralCode
    );
}

function executeOperation(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 premium,
    address initiator,
    bytes calldata params
) external override returns (bool) {
    //logic.....

    //cALCULAR PRIMA
    uint256 fee = LowGasSafeMath.add(amount, premium);
    IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), fee);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the bracket '}' that you opened in the contract.
Check if is only that what is causing that error.
Too I'm seeing that you imported 'SafeMath' and not 'LowGasSafeMath'.

Comment: Thanks i'll chek it, i closed the bracket when copied the code y i just skiped it